# Backup MySQL com Event Scheduler

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, backup, scheduler

Gostaria de alguma dica de como fazer um backup de um banco de dados mysql com Event Scheduler.

Eu só consegui nas minhas pesquisas, achar event para fazer back de tabelas individualmente.
Gostaria de poder fazer o backup do banco todo, alguem pode me ajudar?

*(este código é apenas um teste que estou fazendo no localhost)*

```
SET @sql_text = 
   CONCAT (
   "SELECT * FROM ?i dont know? INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Eiglimar\Desktop\backup_mysql"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
   , "BonInterne.csv'"
);

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;

delimiter |

CREATE EVENT BackUpCSV
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE s1;
  END |

delimiter ;

DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer o backup de todas as tabelas recomendo o comando [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). Exemplo:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/bk/arquivo.cnf schema > /home/bk/backup_mysql.sql
```

Onde `arquivo.cnf` contém as informações de acesso:

```
[mysqldump]
user=meu_user
password=minha_senha
```

Você pode agendar jobs do [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (ou no [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) se estiver utilizando Windows) para fazer isso de forma recorrente.

A abordagem de eventos agendados no MySQL, como você mesmo observou, é recomendada para backups de tabelas individuais.

Ainda que seja possível consultar quais são as tabelas de um *schema* através do [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html), e com isso criar uma lógica de backup genérica, certamente essa abordagem seria mais custosa e de difícil manutenção.

---

**Fonte:** [Learning MySQL - Automating Backups](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/scheduling_backups).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado estava nessa dúvida cruel, mas para fazer recorrente então só "agendar" lá no Task Scheduler mesmo ne? mais uma vez obrigado!