# Como restaurar banco de dados para recuperar dados?

Tags: mysql

O Mysql existe algum sistema de backup automático? Na minha tabela havia um campo CNPJ que continha CNPJs e CPFs, era do tipo `varchar` alterei para o tipo `int` e ferrou com tudo.

Comment: Sempre faça um backup antes de alterar qualquer coisa em um banco de dados que esteja em produção.

Comment: Você configurou para fazer back up no servidor? alguma cron?  algo para fazer automaticamente? senão e bem pouco provável.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não sei se é duplicata. Pela descrição, ele quer saber se o mysql faria, sozinho, por padrão, algum backup que permitiria que ele recuperasse os dados que perdeu.

Comment: Eu também acho que esses são os únicos caminhos pra backup. Por isso a resposta aqui seria "não", @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @bfavaretto pois é, me foquei no titulo e na primeira linha, ajustei a pergunta para evitar confusões

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio eu que **não** exista nada pronto, a não ser que o teu servidor/administradores tenham implementado algo, então só entrando em contato com o suporte técnico e/ou administradores do servidor para solicitar uma cópia do backup.

Caso não tenha nada implementado em teu servidor não será possível restaurar.

Quando for fazer modificações é sempre bom testar na sua máquina local primeiro, para evitar estes tipos de problemas.

Sugestões de backup para evitar problemas *futuros*:

- [Como fazer backup diários de Banco de Dados Mysql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3470/3635)
- [Realizar backup automatico MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70123/3635)
- [Backup automático com MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230872/3635)
- [Backup MySQL com Event Scheduler](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45853/3635)